# Chart.js legend colors

Tags: legend, chart.js

What am I doing wrong regarding legend colors? They appear gray and doesn't inherit the bar colors.

It looks like this: [image: Missing colors on chart.js legends]

Also, can you avoid repeating the bar colors in each dataset and define the colors outside the dataset array instead?

This is how my JS looks like (I'm using the latest version):

```
var matchChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["Today", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Total"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Invites sent',
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)'
            ],
            data: [60, 30, 25, 82]
        },
        {
            label: 'Invites declined',
            color: '#9CBABA',
            backgroundColor: [
               'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)'
            ],
            data: [40, 20, 75, 12]
        },
        {
            label: 'Invited Accepted',
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)'
            ],
            data: [22, 34, 75, 92],
        },
        {
            label: 'Diaglogues started',
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.24)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.24)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.24)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.24)'
            ],
             data: [10, 34, 65, 42],
        },
    ]
}
```

});

Comment: Have you found a solution? I can consistently reproduce on Safari, but not on Chrome

Comment: This is a long shot, but I am also experiencing same issue. Any suggestions to try ?